# creating a column based on values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 50], 'b': [5, 2, 20]})
```

And this is the output that I need:

```
    a   b    c
0  10   5    1005
1  20   2    1009.02
2  50  20    1109.922
```

I want to create column `c`. I have an initial value which is 1000. The first line of `c` is calculated like this:

```
x = 1000 * (10 / 100)     # 10 is first line of column a
y = 1 + (5 / 100)         # 5 is first line of column b
z = 1000 - x

result = (x * y) + z
```

The second row of `c` is:

```
x = 1005 * (20 / 100)     # 20 is second line of column a
y = 1 + (2 / 100)         # 2 is second line of column b
z = 1005 - x

result = (x * y) + z
```

The same logic applies for that last row of `c`. 1005 is the result of the calculation form the first line.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
df['c'] = ((df.a / 100 * (1 + df.b / 100)).cumprod() * 1000) + 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your next result relies on previous result, you can do a straight forward loop

```py
init_val = 1000
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    x = init_val * (row['a'] / 100)
    y = 1 + (row['b'] / 100)
    z = init_val - x
    init_val = (x * y) + z
    df.loc[idx, 'd'] = init_val
```

```
print(df)

    a   b         c         d
0  10   5  1005.000  1005.000
1  20   2  1009.020  1009.020
2  50  20  1109.922  1109.922
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
def calculate_c(series, prev_result=1000):
    x = prev_result * (series['a'] / 100)
    y = 1 + (series['b'] / 100)
    z = prev_result - x
    result = (x * y) + z
    return result

results = np.zeros(len(df))
prev_result = 1000

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result = calculate_c(row, prev_result)
    prev_result = result
    results[index] = result

df['c'] = results
```

Output:

```
    a   b         c
0  10   5  1005.000
1  20   2  1009.020
2  50  20  1109.922
```